# I need solutions for thumb map and big map but without loading google map twice

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map for showing the local shops.

In design, there is a small map (200x200) on the right of the whole page, after clicking a button, it will show you a bigger map (800x600) with full controls (use lightbox effect).

I wonder if there is any solution that I don't need to load the map twice? As the location/point is the same for two maps, just the different size.

At the moment I can think of is to use a html/php file to load the map, then use iframe to load that file in the main page. but the problem I can imagine is that how can it be centered in both small and the big map (html container)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is a HTML-element, you may place it somewhere else inside a `document`(without reloading any content of the element), e.g. in a LightBox.

The center may be stored before the lightbox will be opened and re-assigned when the map has been inserted into the lightbox.

Demo (using fancybox): [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/TECM4/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/TECM4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dr.Molle. That's amazing demo. Although I can read most of the scripts, there are some doubts, and I hope you can help:  beforeLoad: function (a) {
                      this.content.data({ 
                          parent: this.content.parent(),//what does this do?
                          center: map.getCenter()
                      })
        Also, this "this.content.appendTo(this.content.data('parent')).show(); "  Thank you very much for your time

Comment: It stores the center of the map and the parent element of the map in a variable. The reason for the center is explained in my answer...to recenter the map inside the fancybox. The parent is redundant, a leftover when I made the demo(I thought the map did not return to it's original position when the fancybox has been closed(because the map disappears), so I used this variable to place it back there), but my guess was wrong, it was back at the original position, so it was sufficient to call show() .  Updated version without the redundant code: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/mpQwy/

Comment: Thank you very much for your explaination and sorry for being a script newbie. Does "this" in all "this.content" refers to "map.getDiv()"? I try to do my own using colorbox, but fails, if you have time could you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18370945/1479264

Comment: `this.content` basically refers to the same element as `map.getDiv()`, but `this.content` is a jQuery-object, while `map.getDiv()` returns a `DOMNode`

Answer (score 0):

have a look at  google map's static images

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: Yep, what James said.  A solution I've seen before is, display the small static map by default.  When the user clicks on it, load in the Javascript API version.