# Why my google map resize is not working?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, colorbox

What I am trying to do is, to show a small google map by default, when users click a button, it will show a bigger map.

As it is the same location, I don't want to load the map again, also, I cannot imagine if someone abuses your system by click the button again and again, which will result in loading the google map again and again.

I use [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) to load the bigger map. The problem now is the bigger map does not resize properly, which has some gray area, and the marker is not centered. I don't have the sufficient reputation to post the image. The image link is http://postimg.org/image/g3i9pxns1/. Thank you guys!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var goo = google.maps, mapcenter = new goo.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961)
    function initialize() {
        mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: mapcenter,
            mapTypeId: goo.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        },
        map = new goo.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                mapOptions),
        marker = new goo.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: map.getCenter()
        });

        $('#fancybutton').colorbox({
            inline: true, href: "#map_canvas", width: 800,
            height: 600,
            onOpen: function (a, z) {
                goo.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                map.setOptions({
                    disableDefaultUI: false,
                    center: mapcenter
                })
                map.setCenter(mapcenter);
            },

            onLoad: function (a) {
                goo.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                map.setOptions({
                    center: mapcenter
                })
            },
            onClose: function () {
                goo.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            }
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

html:

```
<div style="width:200px;height:200px">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="fancybutton" value="open fancybox" />
```

Comment: based on the picture, I think your map has resized but not loaded all the tiles. have you tried dragging the map or zooming out

Comment: You are triggering the resize event in the onLoad event. Why not in the onOpen?

Comment: Well, I just tried dragging /zooming, it still shows one fourth of the whole map. Chad, I put it in the onOpen, and it is the same result. Also, guys, the map is not centered.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Hopefully someone else will be able to jump in with a better solution, but I solved it by adding something like this to the resize event:

```
map.panBy(1,1);
setTimeout(function(){map.panBy(-1,-1);},250);
```

It shifts the map by a pixel, then back again and should load the missing tiles.

Comment: Thanks Huckleberry, unfortunately, it does not work for my case.